# How to create multiple inputs for qr code generator?

Tags: javascript

Good Day,

I have a piece of code which generates qr code:

```
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");

function makeCode () {      
    var elText = document.getElementById("text");

    if (!elText.value) {
        alert("Input a text");
        elText.focus();
        return;
    }

    qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
}

makeCode();

$("#text").
    on("blur", function () {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });
```

I use following library: [enter link description here](https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js)

Html:

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="Tee Time:" style="width:80%" /><br />
```

Could You please help to create instead of single input - doubled input?

Comment: you should include your html

Comment: My fault. just added